# Python: Read xml and search for missing files

Tags: python, xml, file, replace, reconnect

I'm looking to reconnect my missing files through Python! Is it possible to read an XML file and get the name of the files in between the tags  example:

```
<Name>A013_C025_08264E.MOV</Name>
<Name>A002_C001_BLABLA.MOV</Name>
```

Then search for that Files `A013_C025_08264E.MOV, etc` in the whole external drive copy his related path and replace in the XML the element `<path>...</path>` with the `<path>ACTUAL PATH FOR A013_C025_08264E.MOV</path>`

for more than 300 files.

XML snippet:

```
<Media ObjectUID="01718186-c2f3-4c48-9d1a-6305067a5184" ClassID="7a5c103e-f3ac-4391-b6b4-7cc3d2f9a7ff" Version="19" Index="4294967295">
    <IsProxy>false</IsProxy>
    <ActualMediaFilePath></ActualMediaFilePath>
    <RelativePath>../../../../A010_C004_0829D8.MOV</RelativePath>
    <StreamNumber>0</StreamNumber>
    <SingleAudioChannel>-1</SingleAudioChannel>
    <IgnoreAudio>false</IgnoreAudio>
    <IgnoreVideo>false</IgnoreVideo>
    <ConformedAudioRate>9223372036854775807</ConformedAudioRate>
    <CaptureStatus>0</CaptureStatus>
    <OfflineReason>5</OfflineReason>
    <Infinite>false</Infinite>
    <LogComment></LogComment>
    <AlternateTapeName></AlternateTapeName>
    <AlternateStart>0</AlternateStart>
    <FileKey></FileKey>
    <Title>A010_C004_0829D8.MOV</Title>
    <ImplementationID>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</ImplementationID>
    <Node Version="1">
    </Node>
    <VideoStream ObjectRef="1884"/>
    <TapeName>001</TapeName>
    <FilePath>A010_C004_0829D8.MOV</FilePath>
    <Start>15742672473528000</Start>
</Media>
```

Where we need to get the name in the tags `<title>` search for the file and place his path in the `<file path>`.

Comment: Yes it is possible, can you post a snippet of your XML?

Comment: To manipulate XML, you can either look into the lxml library or BeautifulSoup.  The latter is probably more user friendly.

To look through your directories, you can look into `os.walk`.

Comment: Explain more... Do you have a single XML files with filenames, and paths, inside, or you have MULTIPLE xml files, or... It's not clear, but most probably we could help you if you provide more information!

Comment: I've seen your edit, but still not much help. What's the relation between `Name` and `path` tags? Is one inside the other, or are they both inside another parent tag with a known name? Is there a one-to-one or one-to-many or many-to-one relation?

Comment: As you can see i believe is just enough to replace the <filepath>, replace <actualmediafilepath> and <relativepath> is not necessary

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this to read the xml files:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup

xml_file = open("my_xml_file.xml", "r")

soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(xml_file.read())

print soup.prettify()
```

Then you can just traverse the xml however you wish to find what you need.

You can use `os.walk` then to look for the files in the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the xml.etree.ElementTree to parse your xml file.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os
import fnmatch
tree = ET.parse('fileName.xml')
root = tree.getroot()


#find all media elements
for media in root.findall('Media'):
    movName = media.find('Title').text
    #find the path to the file
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('src'):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, movName):
            #set the path in the XML file
            media.find('FilePath').text = os.path.join(root, movName)
            #remove the relative path element
            media.remove(RelativePath)
tree.write('fileName.xml)
```

I havent tested this out, might have errors in it.

You should read the docs for more info:

1. http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html
2. http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html